# convert docker run to docker-compose.yml special args

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the folllowing commands that I need to convert to docker-compose

`docker run \
    -p 993:993 \
    -p 587:587 \
    -v /home/vmail:/home/vmail \
    -e MAILNAME="somedomain.com"
    -v /etc/postfix
    -v /etc/dovecot
    -v /etc/ssl
    -v /etc/opendkim
    -v /var/log/container:/var/log
    email
    --email youremail@somedomain.com`

How do I pass the `--email` arg to the `ENTRYPOINT` using docker-compose?

Answer (score 0):

Docker compose has an [entrypoint property](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint) which you can use.

```
...
entrypoint:
    -email=youremail@somedomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
command: my_app --email youremail@somedomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I need the same thing, actually how to map ports in compose like docker run -p provides. I still want to use the docker-compose up to start tho.

I think the ports option on docs page is the answer.
Add this to your compose yaml file:

```
ports:
- "127.0.0.1:<host-port>:<container-port>"
```